# Ubuntu dock show windows from all workstations

Tags: gnome, dock

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS with Gnome shell 42.9. I have a 4x4 array of workspaces. The problem is that the Dock shows only the windows from the current workstation. It used to show all the windows from all the workstations. Without that, I have to sequence through all the workstations to find a window that I want to work with.

Dash to Dock shows the following settings:

1. [X] Show pinned applications
2. [X] Show running applications
3. [ ] Isolate workspaces

How do I get the Dock to show all the windows from all the workspaces? E.g., I usually have 8 Firefox windows open, with specific topics in separate workspaces, so all the firefox windows are grouped under the Dock's Firefox icon.

Comment: You do not have a default setup. So to debug, disable the Gnome Shell extension you use, log out then back in and check whether now, windows from all workspaces are shown on the dock or not. If yes, then you know the problem lies with the extension. If no, then other users also should be able to reproduce your problem, which can help finding the cause.